# How to disable autocorrection/autocompletion but not the spellcheck/errorcheck in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I want to disable autocorrection/autocompletion, like the automatic insertion of `]` when I type `[` and also other autocorrection/autocompletion options in TeXstudio. But I want to keep allspellcheck/errorcheck so, that TeXstudio will show me that I typed not correctly but will not autocorrect/autocomplete mistakes. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on the `Show Advanced Settings` in the bottom right corner, switch to `Adv. Editor` and disable `Auto Complete Parenthesis`. Like this:
[image]

Under `Options>Configure TeXstudio>Completion` turn off `Automatic start completer ...`, `Auto complete common prefixes` and `Auto Insert Math ...`.  Like this:

[image]

Comment: It worked. I edited and added pictures. Also, "Show adv options" needed for "Completion" menu for all needed options to appear, so made edit accordingly.

Comment: @vasili111 Perfect. I accepted the edit :)